# Eclipse WebLogic root directory

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I am working on a JSF 2.0 development project that uses some external header and footer files that I do not own and cannot edit.  The html header and footer files reference images and css that are referenced as such `/images/corp_logo.gif`.

I previously had the project working correctly in Tomcat 7.0 by putting the image and css directories at the tomcat root here:

`C:\Users\1234\Documents\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\ROOT`

However when I changed to WebLogic, I cannot find the correct directory where the files should reside.  The domain is located in this directory:

`C:\Users\1234\Documents\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0`

If I "Copy image location"  I get 
`http://localhost:7001/images/corp_logo.gif`

Where should I copy my image and css directories so that WebLogic will display the page correctly?   I've already tried `C:/images`, the metadata directory, the weblogic install directory but nothing is working.

I am using Eclipse Indigo with WebLogic 10.3.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: If you can COPY the images to C:/images , why don't you just copy images to WAR directory? Or why not just make a standalone web app whose name is images with all the images inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put Apache in front of the WebLogic and use aliases for the image directories in httpd.conf.

```
Alias /images C:/fddt_dev/images
<Directory C:/fddt_dev/images>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```